# How many initial possible pairings are there for a single-elimination ping-pong tournament involving $n$ players where $n=2, 4$, and $8$?

Tags: probability, combinations

> How many initial possible pairings are there for a single-elimination ping-pong tournament involving $n$ players where $n=2, 4$, and $8$?

Probability class. Should be very simple, but I don't understand the actual question!!

Can somebody verify if my thinking is correct? For $n=2$, there would be a single initial possible pairing. For $n=4$, would there be ${4 \choose 2}$? The wording of the question is throwing me off.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $(a_i,a_j)$ denote that $a_i$ and $a_j$ are paired together. Note that $(a_i,a_j)$ and $(a_j,a_i)$ mean the same thing.

If you have $a_1,a_2,\cdots , a_{2n}$

Fill the blanks:

$$\underbrace{(\ ·\ ,\ ·\ ),(\ ·\ ,\ ·\ ),(\ ·\ ,\ ·\ )\cdots (\ ·\ ,\ ·\ )}_n$$

You have to take into account that the order in wich you write the pairings doesn't matter.

You should get:

> $$\displaystyle\frac{(2n)!}{n!2^n}$$

Comment: I don't understand... Why are there 2n players instead of n? And how did you come up with what an "initial pairing" was?

Comment: $n$ denotes the number of pairings. (You need an even number to pair up everyone). I didn't come up with any initial pairing. I used $(a_i,a_j)$ as a notation.